# not restrict to id attribute to build an URL with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor

we want to not restrict to id attribute to build an anchor , but also , Css selector .

Example :

```
http://mysiteoryoursite.com/mypage/or/yourpage#idOfPTag
```

THat it means , if page contains an element with id equals to idOfTag , go to this element :

## Now,we wanna be more free :

i.e:

```
http://mysiteoryoursite.com/mypage/or/yourpage#$div:eq(2)
```

that it means : go to the second div in the page :

```
   http://mysiteoryoursite.com/mypage/or/yourpage#$p:eq(8)
```

==>Go to 8th paragraph in page

Comment: This is not a good idea for security reasons. If you put what is in the fragment of the URL into a jQuery selector you are giving someone COMPLETE control of your website.

Comment: `have a look at window.location.hash`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I disagree. There are safe ways to go about it. OP what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash.substring(2)).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zusud/1)

[DEMO Source](http://jsbin.com/hebet/1/edit)

Comment: But it is the same logic of @Abdennour's answer .. Have u another logic but scrolling ?

Comment: they share some logic ...but they aren't the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes , we can :

```
 $('body').scrollTo(window.location.hash.substr(2),{duration:'slow'});
```

## Enjoy Demo:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wmB5K/5/show/#$p:eq(18)
```

And to trigger event for a tag which are such the following :

```
<a href="#$p:eq(20)">Go to p:eq(20) </a>
```

We can add to our code:

```
$(document).delegate('a[href^="#$"]','click',function(){
   $('body').scrollTo($(this).attr('href').substr(2),{duration:'slow'});

});
```

## [Source Code:](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wmB5K/5/)